# active record virtual model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model and an email model. The user can create emails and receive them. A received email is realy just an email, but joined to the user on different field. My setup is below, but it doesn't work correctly. When I call received_messages on a user that created an email (and did not receive it) he also sees a message.
Is this possible at all this way?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mail_messages
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'MailMessage', foreign_key: 'to_id'
end

class MailMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
emd
```

I did create a controller for these messages:

```
class ReceivedEmailsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    messages = current_user.received_messages

    if messages
      render json: messages, each_serializer: MailMessageSerializer, status: :ok
    else
      render json: :nothing, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def show
    message = current_user.received_messages.where(id: params[:id]).first

    if message
      render json: message, serializer: MailMessageSerializer, status: :ok
    else
      render json: :nothing, status: :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

The tests:

```
  describe ReceivedEmailsController do

    let!(:main_user) { Fabricate :user }
    let!(:receiving_user) { Fabricate :user }
    let!(:message) { Fabricate :mail_message, user_id: main_user.id, to_id: receiving_user.id }

    describe 'get index' do

      it 'should give not found when there are no emails received' do
        main_user.confirm!
        sign_in main_user
        get :index
        JSON.parse(response.body)['received_emails'].size.should eq 0
      end
    end
  end
```

Instead of 0 I get 1 back, the same message that I get back when doing the test via the receiving_user. I want to get the message back via the receiving_user but not via the main_user.

I'm not sure whether it can be done this way, whether to use scopes, or even something else I'm not aware of.

Thanks.

Comment: I would think that you'd want a join table between users and messages to allow multiple recipients, each of which could be "to", "cc", or "bcc".

Answer (score 0):

One of your let! statements fabricates an email which belongs to main_user, so you get, correctly one result.

UPDATE

The above is incorrect. Try `if messages.any?` instead of `if messages` as it will always return true, since associations returns an array (empty array if there are no matching records)

Comment: but the ReceivedEmailsController gets the index through current_user.received_messages, I only want emails in that case where the current_user.id is equal to the to_id from a MailMessage